How to publish Geopackage service with Domain in Geoserver
I followed the guidelines to publish Geopackge, but I got an error from Geoserver
enter image description here
I want to Publish Geopackage with Domain Using Geoserver, because attribute table should contain Domain value field like dropdown. in addition i tried publish by using GeoCat Bridge in QGIS, that is also give some errors "Failed to create datastore polygon_feature from C:\Users\sivar\AppData\Local\Temp\geocatbridge\3f310cf83e75460a8430b28763d1dcfb\polygon_feature.gpkg: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8080): Max retries exceeded with url: /geoserver/rest/workspaces/test/datastores/polygon_feature/file.gpkg?update=overwrite (Caused by ResponseError('too many 500 error responses'))"
